# Settings (gnome-control-center) does not open in 19.10

Tags: gnome, settings, 19.10

The settings app does not open at all. I have tried restarting the computer, uninstalling and reinstalling `gnome-control-center`. Neither method worked. I don't remember doing anything that may cause this issue.

When I run `sudo gnome-control-center` from the terminal, this is the result:

```
**
ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Bail out! ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Aborted
```

Comment: Did you try from terminal?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yep. Gives an error. I've put the details into the original question.

Comment: Just to eliminate a problem with your local account, create a new account... called Guest, or Test, whatever. Then log into that new account and try settings. If it works, let me know and I'll give you further steps. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: status please...

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. I ended up wiping my entire partition and installing Kubuntu. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having the same problem. I am on a Debian 10 system running Cinnamon.

I did find a workaround at

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1645855

by doing the following in a bash shell:

```bsh
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. (Debian 10, no gdm3)

Comment: Worked for me as well (Kubuntu 19.10), thanks a lot!